# how to create a Metro ui toggle switch control in winforms c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, microsoft-metro, custom-controls

im trying to implement a toggle switch control in winforms c# i want to recreate the windows 8 pc setting toggle switch control as a metro ui (microsoft design style...whatever!)

http://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Windows-8-PC-Settings-Sync.png

i need help or direction how to start to create the control?

Answer (score 1):

you can look at my project at github:
https://github.com/viperneo/winforms-modernui

i have implemented an toggle switch control there

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use these type of components, is using component dlls that have the feature already worked and developed with optimal performance, check these:

http://www.devcomponents.com/
http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/WhatsNew2012v1/winforms.xml

However, you can find open source projects, or examples of how to develop this in source code repositories like codeplex and codeproject, see this:

http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=metro%20components&ac=3

there is only one detail ... as seen in the link above, you will find more resources for these type of development in WPF.